# How to efficiently filter out duplicate objects in a list based on multiple properties in Python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python project where I have a list of custom objects, and I need to filter out duplicates based on multiple properties of these objects. Each object has three properties: `id`, `name`, and `timestamp`. I want to consider an object as a duplicate if both the `id` and `name` properties match another object in the list. The `timestamp` property should not be considered when determining duplicates.

Here's an example of what the custom object class looks like:

```py
class CustomObject:
    def __init__(self, id, name, timestamp):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.timestamp = timestamp
```

And a sample list of objects:

```py
data = [
    CustomObject(1, "Alice", "2023-01-01"),
    CustomObject(2, "Bob", "2023-01-02"),
    CustomObject(1, "Alice", "2023-01-03"),
    CustomObject(3, "Eve", "2023-01-04"),
    CustomObject(2, "Bob", "2023-01-05"),
]
```

In this case, I want to remove the duplicates and keep the objects with the earliest `timestamp`.

The expected output should be:

```py
[
    CustomObject(1, "Alice", "2023-01-01"),
    CustomObject(2, "Bob", "2023-01-02"),
    CustomObject(3, "Eve", "2023-01-04"),
]
```

I know that I can use a loop to compare each object with every other object in the list, but I'm concerned about the performance, especially when the list gets large. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this in Python, possibly using built-in functions or libraries?

Comment: What is the date format? Is it YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-DD-MM?

Answer (score 1):

```
class CustomObject:
    def __init__(self, id, name, timestamp):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.timestamp = timestamp
import pandas as pd

data2 = [
    CustomObject(1, "Alice", "2023-01-01"),
    CustomObject(2, "Bob", "2023-01-02"),
    CustomObject(1, "Alice", "2023-01-03"),
    CustomObject(3, "Eve", "2023-01-04"),
    CustomObject(2, "Bob", "2023-01-05"),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(([vars(f) for f in data2]))

df.sort_values(['id', 'name', 'timestamp'])
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'name'], keep='first', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

```
   id   name   timestamp
0   1  Alice  2023-01-01
1   2    Bob  2023-01-02
3   3    Eve  2023-01-04
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a few changes to your class to be usable in a `set`:

```
class CustomObject:
    def __init__(self, id, name, timestamp):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
```

Now you can just make a `set` from the list:

```
set(data)
```

If the data is not already sorted by date, you will need to do that first.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement __gt__ in your class, you can make your code more concise. The comparison between objects is based on the timestamp value which is assumed to be YYYY-MM-DD format. This will **not** work for other datetime formats as it's merely a lexical comparison:

```
class CustomObject:
    def __init__(self, _id, name, timestamp):
        self._id = _id
        self._name = name
        self._timestamp = timestamp
    def key(self):
        return self._id, self._name
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, type(self)) and self._timestamp > other._timestamp
    def __str__(self):
        return f'ID={self._id}, name={self._name}, timestamp={self._timestamp}'


data = [
    CustomObject(1, "Alice", "2023-01-03"),
    CustomObject(2, "Bob", "2023-01-05"),
    CustomObject(1, "Alice", "2023-01-01"),
    CustomObject(3, "Eve", "2023-01-04"),
    CustomObject(2, "Bob", "2023-01-02"),
]

results = dict()

for obj in data:
    if (co := results.get(key := obj.key())) is None or co > obj:
        results[key] = obj

print(*results.values(), sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
ID=1, name=Alice, timestamp=2023-01-01
ID=2, name=Bob, timestamp=2023-01-02
ID=3, name=Eve, timestamp=2023-01-04
```